# how to create matrix of joint distribution P[x,y] from a table of dataset

Tags: r

for example there is table have 100 pairs of x and y value, how can I create matrix of joint distribution P[x,y] in r. I tried to solve it, but no idea how to start

Comment: See `?table`  ...

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 2):

For example, lets derive `x` and `y` from categorical distributions like

```
library(extraDistr)

x <-rcat(100,rep(1,6)/6)
y <- rcat(100, rep(1,4)/4)
z <- cbind(x,y)
```

where `z` is joint sample. Then,

```
library(dplyr)

z %>%
  as.data.frame %>%
  group_by(x,y) %>%
  table()/dim(z)[1]

   y
x      1    2    3    4
  1 0.02 0.06 0.01 0.02
  2 0.04 0.05 0.06 0.08
  3 0.06 0.03 0.04 0.03
  4 0.02 0.03 0.04 0.05
  5 0.04 0.04 0.07 0.02
  6 0.07 0.04 0.01 0.07
```

gives you an sample joint distributions for discrete variables.

## With @Alex's data

```
dummy <- read.csv("x.csv")
head(dummy)
  x y
1 3 3
2 1 3
3 1 3
4 2 2
5 1 4
6 3 4
```

Apply same code above.

```
dummy %>%
  as.data.frame %>%
  group_by(x,y) %>%
  table()/dim(z)[1]

   y
x      1    2    3    4
  1 0.03 0.11 0.20 0.09
  2 0.01 0.09 0.16 0.04
  3 0.03 0.10 0.11 0.03
```

Comment: but values values are not replicated, such as : x:  3 1 1 2 1 3 2 3 2 2 2 3 3 1 1 2 1 2 1 1 2 3 1 2 3 2 2 2 3 1 2 2 2 1 1 3 3 1 2 3 1 1 1 1 1 2
 1 1 1 1 1 1 3 1 1 3 1 1 1 3 1 1 3 1 2 2 3 3 1 1 3 3 2 3 2 1 2 3 3 2 1 3 2 1 2 1 1 2 2 3 3 3 1 2 1 1 3 1 2 2. y:  3 3 3 2 4 4 2 4 3 2 2 1 2 3 3 2 3 3 2 4 3 2 3 3 3 1 3 3 1 4 2 4 2 3 3 3 3 3 4 3 4 4 3 2 2 2 3 2 4 4 4 3 2 3 2 3 3 2 3 3 4 3 3 3 3 4 2 2 3 2 3 1 3 2 3 3 3 2 3 3 2 2 4 1 3 3 2 2 3 2 4 2 2 3 1 2 3 1 3 3

Comment: @Alex Can you provide some sample of your data?

Comment: here is the data: x: 3 1 1 2 1 3 2 3 2 2 2 3 3 1 1 2 1 2 1 1 2 3 1 2 3 2 2 2 3 1 2 2 2 1 1 3 3 1 2 3 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 3 1 1 3 1 1 1 3 1 1 3 1 2 2 3 3 1 1 3 3 2 3 2 1 2 3 3 2 1 3 2 1 2 1 1 2 2 3 3 3 1 2 1 1 3 1 2 2.       y: 3 3 3 2 4 4 2 4 3 2 2 1 2 3 3 2 3 3 2 4 3 2 3 3 3 1 3 3 1 4 2 4 2 3 3 3 3 3 4 3 4 4 3 2 2 2 3 2 4 4 4 3 2 3 2 3 3 2 3 3 4 3 3 3 3 4 2 2 3 2 3 1 3 2 3 3 3 2 3 3 2 2 4 1 3 3 2 2 3 2 4 2 2 3 1 2 3 1 3 3

Comment: @Alex I add result above. Please check it out.

Comment: thank you so much! ! ! can you recommend me some resources to learn how to do this kind of problem.

Comment: @Alex Try to find lecture for `dplyr` or `tidyverse`. It will provide basic and some more informations.

Comment: thank you, and this file has 100 pairs value, why the joint distribution table only shows 12 values

Comment: @Alex As I understand your data is from discrete variables, samples `x` is in `1,2,3` and `y` is in `1,2,3,4`. Therefore, available set of `x` and `y` are limited.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach using base R. First provide reproducible data using `dput()`

```
x <- c(3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 
     2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 
     1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 
     3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 
     1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 2)

y <- c(3, 3, 3, 2, 4, 4, 2, 4, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 4, 
     3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 4, 2, 4, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 
     4, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 4, 4, 4, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 
     3, 3, 3, 4, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 4, 
     1, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 4, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 3)
```

Then tabulate:

```
(tbl <- table(x, y))
#    y
# x    1  2  3  4
#   1  3 11 20  9
#   2  1  9 16  4
#   3  3 10 11  3
(tbl.prp <- prop.table(tbl))
#    y
# x      1    2    3    4
#   1 0.03 0.11 0.20 0.09
#   2 0.01 0.09 0.16 0.04
#   3 0.03 0.10 0.11 0.03

sum(tbl)
# [1] 100
```